# Python unit tests: How to patch an entire class and methods

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I am trying to write unittests for existing code which is poorly written and I'm finding it very hard to unit test.

```
def pay(self):
    fraud = NewFraudCheck()
    result, transaction = fraud.verify_transaction()
```

the test I have at the moment, I am patching the NewFraudCheck class

```
@patch checkout.pay.NewFraudCheck
def test_pay(self, mock_fraud_check):
    mock_fraud_check.verify_transaction.assert_called()
```

The test is failing with a ValueError, stating that verify_transaction is not returning enough values to unpack.

I have tried adding

```
mock_fraud_check.verify_data.return_value = (1, 1231231)
```

however this doesn't seemt o have any effect.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues I'll point out, but the question is missing a few details so hopefully I can address them all in one shot:

1. Your syntax here is wrong: `@patch checkout.pay.NewFraudCheck`. It should be `@patch('checkout.pay.NewFraudCheck')`
2. There is a missing class somewhere that has the function `pay(self)` on it. That class lives inside a module somewhere which is important to properly mock `NewFraudCheck`. I'll refer to that missing module as `other`.
3. `NewFraudCheck` needs to be patched at the point where it's looked up. That means, in the mystery module `other` where there's a class that has `pay(self)` defined in it, there's presumably an import of `from pay import NewFraudCheck`. *That* is where `NewFraudCheck` is looked up, so your patch will need to look like this: `@patch('checkout.other.NewFraudCheck`). More info here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch
4. You need to assign/use the return value of your `patch`, not access `verify_transaction` directly off of the mock. For instance, it should read like this: `mock_fraud_check.return_value.verify_transaction.return_value = (1, 1231231)`. Notice the inclusion of `return_value`.

The final test I came up with looked like this and passed:

```
    @mock.patch('checkout.other.NewFraudCheck')
    def test_pay(self, mock_fraud_check):
        # This is the class that lives in mystery module, 'checkout.other' and calls pay()
        other_class = SomeOtherClass()
        mock_fraud_check.return_value.verify_transaction.return_value = (1, 1231231)
        other_class.pay()
        mock_fraud_check.return_value.verify_transaction.assert_called()
```